# American expression for an average weapon

Tags: idioms, american-english

I want to translate the expression

> It's better to hit the target from a Makarov rather than miss from a Glock.

from Russian into English. In Russia, many people know that

- a [Glock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glock) is a fancy, trendy gun, whereas
- the [Makarov pistol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makarov_pistol) is an old, pretty average weapon, workhorse of the army and law-enforcement agencies (nothing fancy about it).

In German, there is an expression [08/15](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/08/15_(Redewendung)), which means *usual, nothing special*, and refers to machine gun [MG 08/15](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MG_08/15), which was commonly used in World War I.

What's the American term for a commonly used, average weapon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the American propensity for violence, there is (as far as I know, and I'm a native speaker) no such thing as a word for "an average weapon". However, I have heard the phrase

> It's better to hit with small than miss with big.

used when the joys of large-caliber weapons comes up.

Answer (score 2):

According to the link from Guns & Ammo Network :

> http://www.gunsandammo.com/blogs/history-books/firearms-nicknames/

There are some word that describe average weapons and handguns:

AKAs such as “Heater”,  Shooting iron”, “Smoke Pole” and “Persuader” are pretty easy to figure out, as are *“Saturday Night Special”*, *“Suicide Special”* and *“Flyapart”*, the latter a trio of terms to describe cheaply-made, inexpensive handguns intended for limited, somewhat specialized usage.

Hope it helps you.